# SQL Server custom number generation Concurrency for POS

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sequence, semaphore

I am working on rewriting a Stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that is used in POS billing process. First step is to get Bill Number which is an auto-rotate sequence number with added prefix.

As the number of concurrent terminal grows ~10-30, we have faced number of issues like duplicate number, dead lock. Optimization that I am currently working on derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108403/solutions-for-insert-or-update-on-sql-server), which improved to an extend (no duplicates). But when I tried to test with [SQLQueryStress](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlQueryStress) based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555471/what-tools-are-available-to-test-sql-statement-performance/1556109#1556109) suggestion using 10 iteration and 10 concurrent thread, I see dead lock in few tests and consistent failure getting the prefix from the same table for the first(few iterations)

Procudure has these currently

> 1. SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
> 2. get the prefix from the same table with (nolock) where type=@type and terminalid=@terminalid
> 3. Begin Tran
> 4. UPDATE Numbering with (serializable)
>      SET @nextval=nextnumber,
>              nextnumber = nextnumber + 1
> 5. if @@rowcount = 0 insert
> 6. Commit tran
> 7. output Format prefix + @nextval

**Note,**
This code snippet will not be Ideal as, I was going back and forth restructuring this.
This is only a section of code of an if else, where the else has the same block repeating with different where condition(for four different scenarios).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetnextNumberTest] 
        @transType varchar(50), -- 
        @terminalaname varchar(50)='',  --will be empty if it is not terminal wise
        @nextvalue varchar(10) output
AS
BEGIN

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

declare @ResetBasedOn int =0
        ,@Prefix varchar(50)=''
        ,@nextvalint int=0


select  @ResetBasedOn=RestartOn,
        @Prefix=((SELECT Prefix FROM TerminalMaster(nolock) WHERE TerminalName=@terminalaname)+'/'+ prefix)
                        from NumberingSchemeTest (nolock)
    where  TRSType= @transType 
        and (TerminalName=@terminalaname or TerminalName='') and active=1


if(@ResetBasedOn=0) --daily
begin

    Begin Tran
        UPDATE Numberingschemetest with (serializable)      
            SET @nextvalint=nextnumber,
            -- 
                nextnumber = nextnumber + 1

        WHERE TRSType= @transType 
            and (TerminalName=@terminalaname or TerminalName='') 
            and yearlydate =convert(varchar, GETDATE()) 
            and active=1 

       if @@rowcount = 0
       begin
            UPDATE Numberingschemetest with (serializable)  
                set active=0
            where  TRSType= @transType 
                and (TerminalName=@terminalaname or TerminalName='') 
                and yearlydate =convert(varchar, GETDATE() -1) 
                and active=1

            insert into  Numberingschemetest (
                TRSType,  
                Prefix,    
                TPrefix,   
                TerminalName,  
                RestartOn, 
                YearlyDate,  
                StartingFrom, 
                NextNumber, 
                active,PreparedBy
                )
            (select top 1  
                TRSType,  
                Prefix,    
                TPrefix,   
                TerminalName,  
                RestartOn,   
                convert(varchar, GETDATE()),  
                StartingFrom, 
                StartingFrom+1, 
                1  ,@terminalaname
            from Numberingschemetest 
                where TRSType= @transType 
                    and (TerminalName=@terminalaname or TerminalName='') 
                    and active=0 )

        End
    Commit Tran
    if(@nextvalint=0)
        set  @nextvalue=@Prefix+'0001' 
    else
    set @nextvalue =@Prefix+RIGHT('000'+ CAST(@nextvalint AS VARCHAR(50)),Case when LEN(@nextvalint)>4 then LEN(@nextvalint) else 4 end)
End
```

All these based on several similar question from this site. At this stage, I could only think of two things. One is split the prefix to a separate table and the other is to try a different tool to do the load testing.

I can understand that there will be some trade off, but want to know the best route forward.

Comment: can you post the proc code?

Comment: @scsimon, any suggestions? Anything to move forward is fine, even if is rethinking on the Architecture. Thanks

Comment: I just noticed you post a private code I will look at this tomorrow

Comment: I think it'd benefit you to check out [Kendra's poster](https://littlekendra.com/sqlserverposters/) on lock hints and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7845331/6167855)